# Catching queries from SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I am looking for something like SQL Server Data Collection but for Analysis Services to log every executed OLAP query. As far as I know SSAS log doesn't provide this information.

Comment: What version and mode of SSAS?

Comment: I have both Olap & Tabular 2016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Profiler connected to SSAS to watch queries live.

Or you can install [ASTrace](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karang/2012/06/05/ssas-monitoring-tool-astrace/) to log queries or any other trace events to a SQL database without a GUI running.

Or you can use a [server side trace](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfebi/2013/02/12/managing-server-side-analysis-services-profiler-trace/) to write to .trc files on disk on the SSAS server. Then you can later load those files to a SQL server database for analysis with a PowerShell script like [this](http://www.bp-msbi.com/2012/02/counting-number-of-queries-executed-in-ssas/).

Or you could use [XEvents](http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2012/05/05/using-xevents-in-ssas-2012/).